# In firefox can't get keyboard focus back from silverlight object in javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, firefox, focus

I have a silverlight object that keeps grabbing keyboard focus and I can't get the focus back.  I have javascript application with a menu where the user can select an option by pressing the "enter" key.  "Enter" works until the user clicks on the silverlight object.  I tried to create a workaround by using this method:

```
Epg.prototype.grabClick = function(screen){
    // Hack for Mac+Firefox - when you click the screen, we must recover focus from Silverlight
    screen.div.click(function(event){
       if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            window.blur();
            window.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

This issue does not happen in Chrome only Firefox.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think window.focus() works properly in firefox. Can you pick some element inside the window and use it to focus?

Comment: You may just have to live with it then, unless you have access to the source code of the object and can somehow force it to release focus through a JS API or otherwise. If an object is actively trying to steal focus, you don't have a lot of options. You can see this behavior almost anywhere an object is embedded in a browser window. Flash applications and embedded PDFs both tend to steal keyboard focus.